# CPU caches aware C++ / C programming

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, cpu-cache

I was going through Scott Meyer's podcast on [CPU CACHES AND WHY YOU CARE](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/cpu-caches-and-why-you-care) It seems this will make code run faster, is there any open source where such coding is done for reference.
Or anybody has example of design of data structures/algorithms based on `CPU caches aware`

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm

Comment: This question is _way_ too broad. How best to structure a data structure for optimal use of the cache depends on a great many things. The access patterns, when you access it, how big the elements are, etc. There's no one catch-all answer; that's why the podcast simply talks about how cached memory works. There's no "do this and your code gets faster" silver bullet.

Comment: If it wasn't phrased too broadly and in the "I have just read a blog that I found interesting" style, this question would still be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763262/cache-efficient-code

Comment: And I found this other vague and general question by looking for something specific on "cache miss performance counter". Nothing turned up on StackOverflow, so you are left with Google, but it you start applying the ideas from the video you liked without having used those first to measure cache efficiency of your existing algorithm, you are wasting your time.

Comment: You'll find many relevant readings in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852670/how-to-write-fast-low-level-code

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the entire Linux kernel is implemented to be cache-aware.

For more details there is highly recommended paper [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Linear algebra is sensitive to cache problems. The [BLAS subroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) allow one to abstract away from these concerns